# Python IDLE equivalent of CTRL-R in R

Tags: python, r

If you have a script open in the Windows version of R, you can run a line (or section of highlighted code) in the shell by hitting CTRL-R (believe it's command-enter in apple version). Is there similar functionality for IDLE? Many thanks

Comment: You might want to look at Spyder's Ctrl + F9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999829/which-python-ide-can-run-my-script-line-by-line

Comment: The advanced text editor in KDE (kate) supports piping code to a console. I think KDE now also runs under Windows (which I suspect is what you use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDLE with [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) supports the ability to run a single line of code or a selection by pressing F9. It also has subCodes which allows you to run code in between '##' comments. It has the same effect as highlighting a lot of code for execution, but you don't need to keep highlighting each time.

Comment: That last comment is worded a bit more positive than is deserved. Basically it means you need to edit your file to enable you to run a specific section. -- Ideally one would like to have both options of course (like in Matlab).

Answer (score 6):

**No**

In the shortcut key list in IDLE, in **Options > Configure IDLE > Keys**, in the **Action - Key(s)** list, one does not find any shortcut key for executing selected code.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there might be an undocumented feature. Found out that the pro version of Wing IDE does the 'run selection' thing so might make the switch, or might dabble in gui customization if I find some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you type part of your search string before hitting Alt+P, then `Alt+P` will find only items starting with what you typed.

Pasting here from my own answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702886/492336