# Python IDLE search in history (similar to Ctrl+R in bash)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, python-idle

Is there an equivalent in the IDLE ide for python to [Ctrl+R in bash](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/navigating-bash-history-with-ctrlr), where you type a part of the line, and it matches it against the history of already entered lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as good as Ctrl+R, but you can type some of the starting text, and then press Alt+P.

So if you type `for` and then press Alt+P, it will find the last line that starts with `for`, if you press it again, it will find the next-to-last line that starts with `for`, and so on.

This only allows you to search for lines starting with the text, however, while Ctrl+R allows you to find lines containing the text anywhere in them.