# Run parts of Python code in visual studio code like with R

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

So I am trying to wean myself of R a bit more where using this keyboard combination:

```
CTRL + Enter
```

allows me to run parts of the code repeatedly (i.e. data frames etc. stay in memory) bit like in a notebook. For Python I can use:

```
CTRL + F5
```

to run all code or:

```
SHIFT + Enter
```

to run code selection but I cannot run code repeatedly like in R (i.e. objects stay in memory)? Am I right? I wish that I am not haha. Any pointer very much appreciated! Thanks!

PS:

Related (?) discussion:

[Python IDLE equivalent of CTRL-R in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475649/python-idle-equivalent-of-ctrl-r-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I completely understand the question. But vsCode does support python notebooks. You can download a Extension called [Jupyter](https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=) to use it in VsCode. After downloading it you can open a `.ipynb` file to open the notebook inside VsCode. There is also online python notebook from Google at [colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com).

You can also download Anaconda and use the Jupyter Notebook that comes with it, as it also supports R. (see: [docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/r-lang/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20environment%20with%20the,select%20New%2C%20then%20select%20R.&text=To%20run%20the%20code%2C%20in,the%20keyboard%20shortcut%20Ctrl%2DEnter.))

Comment: I want to rather write "proper" python code than using POC type jupyter notebooks if that makes sense?

Comment: @cs0815 You can write proper python code using jupyter notebooks. I have run many programs using it including a couple web servers. You can also use `nbconvert` to run them in the command line. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)

Comment: Thanks - I hope you know what i mean with proper code - will look into nbconvert - maybe that's the best option?